# How do I remove orphan packages from a Conda environment?

Tags: conda

I uninstalled some packages in a Conda environment and wanted to remove its unused dependencies, i.e., uninstall the orphan packages. Is there a command for this?

`conda clean -p` isn't what I want since it only removes unused packages from the package cache, but a package won't be mark as unused if it is still installed in an environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought Conda did that automatically when using the `conda remove` command, since it triggers a full re-solve and keeps only the newly solved version. But, for the sake of the question, I’ll take the premise for granted (maybe you deleted something from the file system, or used a force flag, etc.).

I was going to suggest the `--prune` flag (part of `conda env update`), but that seems to have lost its function. Instead, one route would be to recreate the environment. Something like:

```bash
# save a full backup, just in case
conda env export -n foo > foo.full.yaml

# this is the version we’re interested in
conda env export -n foo --from-history > foo.min.yaml

# remove the old one
conda env remove -n foo

# recreate it from already installed packages
conda env create -n foo -f foo.min.yaml --offline

# (optional) clean up unused packages
# conda clean -p
```

Unfortunately, not a one-liner. And hopefully that `--offline` flag does its job - the main thing is we want it recreating the environment only from already installed packages.

### Pip-Installed Packages

Note that the above approach does not work with `pip`-installed packages. While Conda can detect the presence of packages installed by `pip`, it does not track them in the `conda-meta/history` file, and therefore will not include them when using the `--from-history` flag.

Since the `foo.full.yaml` will include `pip`-installed packages, one potential workaround is to edit the `foo.min.yaml` to include specifically that section.